# Consuming Rest api not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

After executing

```java
ResponseEntity<RetrieveAllAttributes> response = 
restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URL + attrPath + shortname + "&attributes=*", HttpMethod.GET, entity, RetrieveAllAttributes.class);
```

I get `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotAcceptable: 406 Not Acceptable: [no body]`

I was following [this](http://org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotAcceptable:%20406%20Not%20Acceptable:%20%5Bno%20body%5D) article.

Here is my HttpEntity:

```java
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Cookie", sessionScopedLdapUser.getToken().get("jsession") + ";" + sessionScopedLdapUser.getToken().get("tpa2"));
                
    headers.set("CSRFToken", sessionScopedLdapUser.getToken().get("csrf"));
              
    HttpEntity<RetrieveAllAttributes> entity = new HttpEntity<RetrieveAllAttributes>(new RetrieveAllAttributes(), headers);
```

When I use `HttpEntity<String>` instead and get a a ResponseEntity of type String I can see the response body

```
[
{"_links":
{"formTemplate":{"href":"xx"},"self":{"href":"xxx","title":"xxx"},"erparent":{"href":"xxx"}},
"_attributes":
{"gender":"F","display":"xx","number":"01000040","mail":"xxx ","fullname":"xxx","title":"Frau","source":"H","givenname":"xxx","erroles":["erpersonstatus":"ACTIVE","postaladdress":"xxx","xhortname":"xxx",}
}
]
```

I also tried using JsonObject and JsonNodes with `ResponseEntity<String>` but is not working ie. I cannot retrieve the value of href:

```java
    if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
    
              JsonNode self_href = rootNode.path("self").path("href"); //---> it does not find the node 
              String hrefAsText = self_href.asText();
```

Any suggestions how it should be done?

Here my consumingrest classes:

```java
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
      public class RetrieveAllAttributes {
          private Links _links;
          private Attributes _attributes;
      
          ... getters and setters
      }
  
      @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
      public class Attributes {
      
          private String id;  
          .... getters and setters
  
      }
  
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Links {
      private Self self;
      .... getters and setters
  }
  
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Self {
      private String href;
      ... getters and setters
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this only returning the restTemplate response as String:

```
responseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URL + attrPath + shortname + "&attributes=*", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
         // parse response body to a JSON object without the first and and last character ie. [ ]
         String body = response.getBody().substring(1, response.getBody().length() - 1);
         JSONObject bodyJson = new JSONObject(body);
    
         // parse value for user href link 
         JSONObject hrefJson = bodyJson.getJSONObject("_links").getJSONObject("self");
         String href = hrefJson.getString("href");
         ...
```